# How to toggle picture src of ImageButton

Tags: java, android, layout

I have an image button and want that when the user clicks on it-it changes its src to a different drawable-but i want the background color i defined in xml to remain the same. Here is the code that i have done so far, but doesnt work, because im changing background and not the source-but general concept i will use:

```
                public void onClick(View view) {
                if (bgenabled == true) {
                    holder.ib.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.location_deactive));
                    bgenabled = false;
                } else { holder.ib.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.location_active));
                         bgenabled = false;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the `setImageDrawable` to replace the current image you are using
with your `ImageButton`.

```
ImageButton button;
...
button.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_image));
```